# Pandas pyplot throwing error "no numeric data to plot" when the dataset clearly has correct data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

So I have this very basic piece of code to just learn Box plots in matplotlib.pyplot , I am following a tutorial where it works perfectly well for the instructor but not me. Its literally the same code, I would like to know if this feature has been like changed or something. [Dataset](https://gist.github.com/ktisha/c21e73a1bd1700294ef790c56c8aec1f)

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# This is taken from CSV but its easily available on the web , epecially kaggle

url ="D:\PycharmProjects\ML\Datasets\pima-indians-diabetes-database\diabetes.csv"
names = ['preg','plas','pres','skin','test','mass','pedi','age','class']
data = pandas.read_csv(url,names = names)

# this is where the issue arises
data.plot(kind='box',subplots = 'True',layout=(3,3),sharex=False,sharey=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You may want to at least link to the dataset or provide a [mcve] in some other way (note: not everyone has a kaggle account).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for the info, I have provided the link in the question

Comment: @RickLesnar it works fine for me

Comment: @Joe That's weird huh!

Comment: @RickLesnar is data imported properly(can you print properly your df)? what version of python do you have?

Comment: @Joe  Yeah , I can print the Data , I am using python 3.5.

Comment: @RickLesnar what error gives you?

Comment: @Joe 'plot'.format(numeric_data.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot

Comment: ah then when you import the data you should say that they are numbers, not string

Comment: @Joe How is it working for you then?Have you modified the code I had given here? Plus how would the column names be converted?

Comment: Works for me too, I ran the very same code except `url = 'https://gist.github.com/ktisha/c21e73a1bd1700294ef790c56c8aec1f/raw/819b69b5736821ccee93d05b51de0510bea00294/pima-indians-diabetes.csv'`

Comment: Because i was taking raw data already numeric from your dataset. The column names are not converted. Add the line i proposed in the answer and check if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before to plot, add this line to your code:

```
data = data.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Comment: I added It , says, "ValueError: ('Unable to parse string "Pregnancies" at position 0', 'occurred at index preg')"

Comment: Use the argument `skiprows`: `data = pandas.read_csv(url,names = names, skiprows=9)` or 
`skiprows=10`

Comment: Wow , That actually worked, Skiprows=9 , Thanks for sticking out till the end. Maybe you can expand your answer,

Comment: You are welcome. When you loaded the csv, you were loading also rows that werecomments or explanations. With skiprows, you avoid them

Comment: Ps, if it is just one row with comment/description/header, you should use skiprows=1 to avoid to skip rows of your df